# Symfony2 form validator groups without entities

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I'm using Symfony2 form component to build and validate forms. Now I need to setup validator groups based on a single field value, and unfortunately it seems that every example out there is based on entities - which im not using for several reasons.

Example:
If task is empty, all constraint validators should be removed, but if not, it should use the default set of validators (or a validator group).

In other words, what I'm trying to achieve is making subforms optional, but still be validated if a key field is populated.

Can someone possible give me an example how to configure it?

```
<?php
namespace CoreBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use CoreBundle\Form\Type\ItemGroupOption;

class ItemGroup extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('title', 'text', array(
            'label' => 'Titel',
            'attr' => array('class' => 'span10 option_rename'),
            'required' => false
        ));
        $builder->add('max_selections', 'integer', array(
            'label' => 'Max tilvalg',
            'constraints' => array(new Assert\Type('int', array('groups' => array('TitleProvided')))),
            'attr' => array('data-default' => 0)
        ));
        $builder->add('allow_multiple', 'choice', array(
            'label' => 'Tillad flere valg',
            'constraints' => array(new Assert\Choice(array(0,1))),
            'choices'  => array(0 => 'Nej', 1 => 'Ja')
        ));
        $builder->add('enable_price', 'choice', array(
            'label' => 'Benyt pris',
            'constraints' => array(new Assert\Choice(array(0,1))),
            'choices'  => array(0 => 'Nej', 1 => 'Ja'),
            'attr' => array('class' => 'option_price')
        ));
        $builder->add('required', 'choice', array(
            'label' => 'Valg påkrævet',
            'constraints' => array(new Assert\Choice(array(0,1))),
            'choices'  => array(0 => 'Nej', 1 => 'Ja')
        ));
        $builder->add('options', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new ItemGroupOption(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false
            )
        );
        $builder->add('sort', 'hidden');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'item_group';
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        global $app;

        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'validation_groups' => function(FormInterface $form) use ($app) {

                // Get submitted data
                $data = $form->getData();

                if (count($app['validator']->validateValue($data['title'], new Assert\NotBlank())) == 0) {
                    return array('TitleProvided');
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            },
        ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using 2.1 you may want to have a look at ["Groups based on submitted data"](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#groups-based-on-submitted-data).

**Update**

Example using the demo contact page `/demo/contact` in the default `AcmeDemoBundle` provided with Symfony Standard Edition :

The form type with conditional validation groups :

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class ContactType extends AbstractType
{
    // Inject the validator so we can use it in the closure
    /**
     * @var Validator
     */
    private $validator;

    /**
     * @param Validator $validator
     */
    public function __construct(Validator $validator)
    {
        $this->validator = $validator;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('email', 'email');
        $builder->add('message', 'textarea', array(
            // Added a constraint that will be applied if an email is provided
            'constraints' => new Assert\NotBlank(array('groups' => array('EmailProvided'))),
        ));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        // This is needed as the closure doesn't have access to $this
        $validator = $this->validator;

        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'validation_groups' => function(FormInterface $form) use ($validator) {
                // Get submitted data
                $data = $form->getData();
                $email = $data['email'];

                // If email field is filled it will not be blank
                // Then we add a validation group so we can also check message field
                if (count($validator->validateValue($email, new Assert\NotBlank())) == 0) {
                    return array('EmailProvided');
                }
            },
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'contact';
    }
}
```

Don't forget to inject the `validator` service in the form type :

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Controller;

//...

class DemoController extends Controller
{
    // ...

    public function contactAction()
    {
        $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(new ContactType($this->get('validator')));

        // ...
    }
}
```

As you can see validation of the `message` field will be triggered only if the `email` field is filled.

Use a diff tool to catch the differences.

Comment: As I clearly stated in my question, I'm not using entities, which that example uses..

Comment: Using entitie is not mandatory. See the closure example. It returns the validation group's name based on submitted data in form. It means you can do whatever checks you want in it with the content of `$form->getData();` and returns a name according to your computation.

Comment: I understand the example, but I'm not sure how to feed it with a matching set of constraints for validation..

Comment: iamdto - I've been following your guidelines, but I fail to get it working. I have updated my code in the question, which "works", by not bugging out, but also it always uses its constraints. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?